# Post tweet option using php only working for me, how to make it general?

Tags: php, twitter

Hi all i developed an application for posting tweet using PHp with twitter api 1.1. But that option is only working for me only. If any one authenticated and try to send tweet using that. It's posting tweet on my wall.

How to make this generalized for anyone.

```
YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx';
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET);
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://xxxx/xxxx/getTwitterData.php');
//print_r($request_token);
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET,    $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$tmessage = $_POST['message'];
$content = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tmessage));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's posting tweets on your wall because you're using access token and secret of the app, or you're the authenticated user. You need to log in the user you want to post for, get their access token and secret, then use consumer key, secret, user access token and user access secret to post on their behalf.
It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but here's a sample post action with Abraham William's library, which you're using:

```
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
$key =  "***";
$secret  = "***";
$token = "***";
$token_secret = "***";
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($key, $secret, $token, $token_secret);
    $message = "whatever";
    $status = $connection->post($message);
    $response= $connection->http_code;
    if($response !=200){
    echo "ERROR";
    }else{
    echo "life is good";
    }
```

Comment: how to get user access token, user access token secret. I think i am already getting them using getRequestToken method

Comment: you're using twitteroauth right? Abraham Williams? There's a test page with code for authentication https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth (index.php)

Comment: I tried to get user accesstokens using this $access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']); But here what is this $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

Comment: I've edited the answer. Still unclear to me what's the problem so I've added a sample connection and post code.

Comment: u r able to post it tweet on your wall. ask other to use what you did and let me know its working or not

Comment: sure I'm able to post on other people's wall and it's working. Still unclear what the problem is here.